# The meaning of the word " Host" in a sentence of a story

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the word "host" mean in the sentence below?
" father O'Mahoney as the light failed, Blacker than ever in his suit and with the black-fringed stole hanging over his shoulders and the white host in his pocket and the darkness in his eyes."

Comment: Just out of interest, given the air of this quote, I would still like to know whether or not it comes from a vampire story or some other area of performance. It is suggestive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Communion wafer used in Christian sacrament, a small white disc.  As explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramental_bread), the word derives from the Latin *hostia* ([defined by Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hostia) as *sacrifice*, *offering* or *victim*).

In Holy Communion (more specifically the Eucharist), deriving from the account of the Last Supper, the host represents the body of Jesus Christ, and red wine represents his blood.  (The wafer takes the place of the bread described at the Last Supper.)  It is argued (for example, see [The Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05573a.htm#section3)) that through *transubstantiation* these symbols actually *become* Christ’s body and blood.  The celebrant (priest) administers a wafer and a sip of wine to each worshipper, in this ceremony of Communion.

Given the morbid and apprehensive tone of your extract, I wonder whether it is from a vampire story.  Stuffing vampires’ mouths with Eucharistic wafers has been one traditional way of killing them–sensibly enough, on the same basis as crucifixes and holy water.

Kerry Clare discusses this in the article ‘[How to Kill a Vampire: Crucifixes, Holy Water and Other Sacred Objects](http://49thshelf.com/Blog/2013/10/31/How-to-Kill-a-Vampire-Crucifixes-Holy-Water-and-Other-Sacred-Objects)’:

> As Montague Summers describes in *The Vampire, His Kith and Kin*,
>   wafers have been found in the tombs of saints such as St. Basil, St.
>   Othman and St. Cuthbert, and even modern-day Greeks were known to
>   place one between the lips of the dead at burial, as protection
>   against vampirism.
>
> [...]
>
> Despite [dramatic weaponised use of the wafer in *Dracula*, and in Coppola’s film adaptation], the sacred wafer
>   defence never really caught on in popular culture as much as the cross
>   or crucifix, probably because that’s a much more dramatic and
>   recognizable prop. Plus, the Eucharist was in many ways replaced by
>   the use of another Christian sacramental: holy water.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this definition of "host" from *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*:

> 1:  the eucharistic wafer or bread before or after consecration